# Swift Google Maps smoothly rounded polylines

Tags: swift, google-maps, dictionary

I'm using GoogleMaps for iOS platform, Swift language.

I draw the path according to the Google Maps documentation:

```
 let path = GMSMutablePath()
 path.add(previousLocation)
 path.add(currentLocation)

 let line = GMSPolyline(path: path)
 line.strokeWidth = 5
 line.strokeColor = .blue
 line.map = mapView
```

My client complains that the route lines intersections must be smoothly rounded. How can I implement this? Some suggestions?

Thanks!

[image: Google Maps Route Polylines]

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution. 
My problem was that I was always drawing only the last two points:

```
 let path = GMSMutablePath()
 path.add(previousLocation)
 path.add(currentLocation)
```

Now, every time when a new location comes, I clear the map and redraw again the entire route:

```
 mapView.clear()

 let path = GMSMutablePath()   
 for location in locationsArray {
     path.add(location)
 }

 let line = GMSPolyline(path: path)
 line.strokeWidth = 5
 line.strokeColor = .blue
 line.map = mapView
```

Seems that in this way Google Maps draws the route correctly. 
[image]

Comment: I want to show progressive polyline draw. any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [SwiftSimplify](https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftSimplify). It is a library that reduces the number of geopoints in the polyline to make it more smooth and efficient.

Comment: The solution is not too lengthy to elaborate with few code, you can post some sort of code instead of suggesting the link completely here.

Comment: @vaibhav: Never used it.

Comment: Can you mention how would you integrate SwiftSimplify to GoogleMaps iOS SDK? I am not getting it.

Answer (score 1):

This library also smooth out the route. I am using this atm. [IVBezierPathRenderer](https://github.com/ivan114/IVBezierPathRenderer)